# Type error when `typescript-fsa-reducers` pulls in incompatible version of `typescript-fsa`

Tags: typescript

I'm using [typescript-fsa](https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa) in my react app, and I'm facing the following behaviour, which I'm not sure if it's a `typescript` limitation, or a limitation of the `typescript-fsa` library, or simply I'm doing things wrong.

I have the following generic function:

```
function CreateAPIOperationReducer<
  TStartPayload
>() {    
  const actionCreator = actionCreatorFactory();

  const actions = {
    start: actionCreator<TStartPayload>(`START`)        
  };
}
```

With the above function, the type of `actions.start` seems o be `(property) start: ActionCreator<TStartPayload>`

However, if I change `TStartPayload`, to let's say a `string`:

```
start: actionCreator<string>(`START`)
```

Then the type of `actions.start` is:

```
(property) start: {
(payload: string, meta?: {
    [key: string]: any;
} | null | undefined): Action<string>;
type: string;
match: (action: AnyAction) => action is Action<string>;
}
```

Which is the expected result of calling `actionCreator`

My question is why with the generic parameter `TStartPayload` I don't see the following as the type of `actions.start`:

```
(property) start: {
(payload: TStartPayload /*<< HERE*/, meta?: {
    [key: string]: any;
} | null | undefined): Action<TStartPayload> /*<< HERE*/;
type: string;
match: (action: AnyAction) => action is Action<TStartPayload> /*<< HERE*/;
}
```

What I also found is if I wrap the generic parameter in an interface, for example:

```
interface IPayloadContainer<Payload> {
  payload: Payload;
}
```

And write the following:

```
start: actionCreator<IPayloadContainer<TStartPayload>>(`START`)
```

Then the type of `start` resembles its type if I use string/number, but this time with the `IPayloadContainer`. Although this works, it's an extra level that I'd like to avoid and the the payload of the action be the actual type I pass, rather than a container over the type.

I'm new to `typescript`, so it's possible I'm missing something obvious.

**EDIT**

It appears like Matt McCutchen said the type being displayed is different to the actual type. I am using [typescript-fsa-reducers](https://github.com/dphilipson/typescript-fsa-reducers) to create the reducer, and with the following code:

```
import actionCreatorFactory from "typescript-fsa";
import { reducerWithInitialState } from "typescript-fsa-reducers";

function CreateAPIOperationReducer<
  TStartPayload
>() {
  interface IAPIOperation {
    pending: boolean;
  }

  const initialState: IAPIOperation = {
    pending: false,
  };

  const actionCreator = actionCreatorFactory();

  const actions = {
    start: actionCreator<TStartPayload>(`START`)
  };

  const reducer = reducerWithInitialState(initialState)
    .case<TStartPayload /*<< HERE*/>(actions.start, (state, payload /* << payload here is of type TStartPayload */) => {      
      return Object.assign({}, state, initialState, {
        pending: true
      });
    })

  return { reducer, actions, initialState };
}
```

I do get the correct type of the payload. However I have to explicitly tell the `case` function the type of the payload, otherwise it will think the type of payload is `{}`. If my payload type was for example a `string`, then I don't need to tell `case` the type and it infers it from the action creator. So I think this is where my confusion came from.

Additionally, if I use the native `isType` function from `typescript-fsa` rather than using `typescript-fsa-reducers`, then the payload is inferred correctly:

```
function reducer(
    state: IAPIOperation = initialState,
    action: typeof actions[keyof (typeof actions)]
  ): IAPIOperation {
    if (isType(action, actions.start)) {
      action.payload /* << Here action.payload is of correct type TStartPayload */
      return Object.assign({}, state, initialState, {
        pending: true
      });
    }
    return state;
  }
```

Comment: This may just be an inconsistency in how the type is displayed and the actual type may be correct.  (You could consider filing an issue after searching for existing ones.)  Do you run into problems using `CreateAPIOperationReducer`?

Comment: Yes if I use the actions created from CreateAPIOperationReducer inside a reducer switch statement, the action payloads are not inferred. Whereas if I use any other type apart from the generic parameter, the action payload is inferred inside the reducer.

Comment: Can you please add example code to the question so I can investigate?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I've edited the question with further details. It appears as you said the displayed type is different to the actual type. I just needed to tell the case function of typescript-fsa-reducers (library being used alongside typescript-fsa) what the type of the payload is. Using the isType function of typescript-fsa works fine as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem if I do the default `npm install typescript-fsa typescript-fsa-reducers`, which gives me `typescript-fsa@3.0.0-beta-2` and `typescript-fsa-reducers@0.4.5`, with the latter having its own copy of `typescript-fsa@2.5.0`.  The inference is failing because `typescript-fsa@3.0.0-beta-2` and `typescript-fsa@2.5.0` have different definitions of `ActionCreator`.  (It's embarrassing how long it took me to realize that!)  The new definition has a conditional type that tests `Payload extends void`; when `Payload` is a concrete type that is known not to be assignable to `void`, the new definition simplifies to be sufficiently similar to the old that your code happened to work, but when `Payload` is the type variable `TStartPayload`, no simplification is possible.

You shouldn't try to use two incompatible versions of `typescript-fsa` together; the compile error may only be the beginning of trouble.  If you want to use `typescript-fsa-reducers`, you should switch your project to a version of `typescript-fsa` that is compatible with it.

Comment: Thanks @MattMcCutchen. I've now installed typescript-fsa@2.5.0 and the inference works as expected now.